# Web audio delay

Tags: web-audio-api

I am using klank.dev to build a simple Karplus Strong string effect.  It works ok up until around F above middle-C but can't get any higher.  The example is pasted below, and you can try it [here](https://link.klank.dev/A9762PRtFzNhm7Gs9) as well (klank only works on Firefox atm).

The line in question is `del: Tuple (g'delay 0.00305) (SProxy :: SProxy "combine")`. If you make the delay longer, ie `0.009`, it gets lower as expected. But if you make it shorter, ie `0.002`, at a certain point the pitch stops going up.

Does web audio have a hard lower limit for delays used in feedback loops?  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DelayNode/delayTime) reports that the minimum value is `0.0`, which works when not used in feedback, but in a feedback loop I'm hitting this problem.  Thanks for any insights!

```hs
module A.Felicidade.Pluck where

import Prelude
import Data.Symbol (SProxy(..))
import Data.Tuple (Tuple(..))
import Data.Typelevel.Num (D1)
import FRP.Behavior (Behavior)
import FRP.Behavior.Audio (AudioUnit, audioWorkletGenerator, g'add, g'delay, g'gain, graph, runInBrowser, speaker')
import Foreign.Object as O
import Record.Extra (SLProxy(..), SNil)
import Type.Data.Graph (type (:/))
import Math(pi, sin, cos)
import Type.Klank.Dev (Klank, Worklets, klank)

worklets :: Worklets
worklets _ res rej =
  ( do
      res [ "https://klank-share.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/K16029410960343210.js" ]
  )

scene :: Number -> Behavior (AudioUnit D1)
scene time =
  pure
    $ speaker'
        ( graph
            { aggregators:
                { out: Tuple g'add (SLProxy :: SLProxy ("combine" :/ SNil))
                , combine: Tuple g'add (SLProxy :: SLProxy ("gain" :/ "mic" :/ SNil))
                , gain: Tuple (g'gain 0.9) (SLProxy :: SLProxy ("del" :/ SNil))
                }
            , processors:
                { del: Tuple (g'delay 0.00305) (SProxy :: SProxy "combine")
                }
            , generators:
                { mic:
                    audioWorkletGenerator
                      "klank-lf-burst"
                      (O.union (O.singleton "nsamples" 15.0) (O.singleton "freq" 1.0))
                }
            }
        ) where rad = time * pi

main :: Klank
main =
  klank
    { run = runInBrowser scene
    , worklets = worklets
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DelayNode` in a loop (cycle) has its delay clamped to a minimum of 1 render quantum.  See https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#DelayNode-attributes.  The time for one render quantum is 128 / sampleRate.  That's about 3 ms for a sample rate of 44.1 kHz.

There's no way to work around this because WebAudio (currently) works in blocks of 128 frames and if you have a cycle, all blocks need 128 frames before producing an output.

The only solution I know of is to implement the part of your graph that's in a cycle using an AudioWorklet.  This, effectively, removes the cycle fro m the graph so you can whatever you need to do.